# Azure ML vs Cortana Analytics Suite

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, cortana-intelligence

I am wondering what is the difference between Cortana Analytics and Azure ML ?

- those are 2 distincts solutions ?
- one is part of the other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Machine Learning is part of the Cortana analytics suite

You will find more info with the link below

[All the details on the Cortana link here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/8/22/what-is-the-cortana-analytics-suite)

All the best

Comment: Cheers @user4640449

Answer (score 1):

Cortana Analytics is the big data and advanced analytics suite of Microsoft. I comes with 6 big pillars.

1. Azure Event Hub
2. Azure Stream Analytics
3. Azure Data Factory
4. Azure Machine Learning
5. Azure SQL Database
6. Power BI

So Azure ML is a part of Cortana Analytics tool